# Linux Cronjob scheduling issue

Tags: linux, oracle, cron, suse, rman

I have a cron job scheduled as below.what it will do is invoke RMAN in Oracle and then clear all the achivelogs in the oracle  database which are 1 day old. But the issue is that it is not getting executed through the cron job. but if I execute the same script  from the prompt it nicely delete the logs through RMAN.  Please help me in sheduling this script...

```
05 07 * * * /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/logde.sh
```

contents of the script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
 /x01/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/rman cmdfile=/x01/rman_backup/mahesh /logdelete.rcv
```

The Content of the logdelete.rcv is as below

```
connect target /
 run
  {
  delete archivelog all completed before 'trunc(sysdate)';
  crosscheck archivelog all;

   }
 exit;
```

Please someone help me in scheduling this. I'm using this in SUSE Linux version 11

Comment: Use output redirection to a file to see whats happening, e.g. ... logde.sh > /tmp/log.txt 2>&1

Comment: like this?   06 12 * * * /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/logde.sh > /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/output.txt

Comment: 06 12 * * * /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/logde.sh > /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/output.txt 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

Generally, use output redirection with your cronjob to collect errors in a file, e.g.

`06 12 * * * /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/logde.sh > /x01/rman_backup/mahesh/output.txt 2>&1`

Specifically, your problem is probably that logdelete.rcv will not be found from cron, as this job will execute in $HOME so the file would need to be there. If it's not, specify the full path to it.

Comment: Message file RMAN<lang>.msb not found

 Verify that ORACLE_HOME is set properly

the above two error appear wht should I change?

Comment: You need to define the binary executing the script: `06 12 * * * /bin/sh ...`

Answer (score 0):

You must have some initializations which are done for your console but not in cron execution. Initialize variables manually or manually source profile files in your cron line.